# Python program to print "hello world" via CUPS?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cups, pycups

```
import cups
conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters()
printer_name = printers.keys()[0]
conn.printFile(printer_name,'/home/pi/Desktop/tempprint.jpg',"Hello",{})
```

how to printFile change to print text example "hello world"? not file.
thank you

Comment: Generate a file first.

Comment: Source code @ https://github.com/Distrotech/pycups/blob/140c5591190b7dfc2516eee7ef9cc0769696ce4c/cupsconnection.c clearly expects a file. As said above dump to a temp file and delete it later

Comment: Do you have a printer installed in the system? Maybe first you should look at [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/169679/how-to-add-a-printer-to-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-computer/)